# Store user's email and password after sign up

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm making social media app that has user profile. I want to save their profile data after they have done their registration. Although the registration is successful, but the user's email and password are not saving in the Firebase database. I've also checked the rules, I use test mode.

Here's my rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
  }
}
```

Here's my codes:

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button btn_signin,btn_signup;
    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword, inputconPassword;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseuser;

    private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN ="((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20})";
    private static  final String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btn_signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signin);
        btn_signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.u_email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.u_password);
        inputconPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.u_conpassword);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        btn_signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!validateForm())
            {
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //create user
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    firebaseuser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                                    User myUserInsertObj = new User(inputEmail.getText().toString().trim(),inputconPassword.getText().toString().trim());
                                    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                                    String uid = firebaseuser.getUid();

                                    ref.child(uid).setValue(myUserInsertObj).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                            {
                                                if(task.isSuccessful())
                                                {
                                                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User data stored.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    finish();
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class));
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    finish();
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main3Activity.class));
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}

    private boolean validateForm()
    {
        boolean valid = true;

        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
        {
            inputEmail.setError("Required.");
            valid = false;
        }

        String password =inputPassword.getText().toString();
        String conpassword = inputconPassword.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
        {
            inputPassword.setError("Required.");
            valid = false;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(conpassword))
        {
            inputconPassword.setError("Required.");
            valid = false;
        }

        if(email.length()>0 && password.length()>0 && conpassword.length()>0)
        {
            if (isEmailValid(email))
            {
                inputEmail.setError(null);
                if (isValidPassword(password))
                {
                    inputPassword.setError(null);
                    if (isValidPassword(conpassword))
                    {
                        inputconPassword.setError(null);
                        if (password.equals(conpassword))
                        {
                            return valid;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password not matched.Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            valid = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password must contains minimum 6 characters at least 1 Lowercase, 1 Uppercase and, 1 Number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    valid = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password must contains minimum 6 characters at least 1 Lowercase, 1 Uppercase and, 1 Number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email invalid.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }

    public static boolean isEmailValid(String email)
    {
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    public static boolean isValidPassword(final String password)
    {
        Pattern pattern;
        Matcher matcher;
        pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no error after I build the project. it builds successfully.

Comment: Lets make it more specific: Are you getting any errors when you are trying to save the user data?

Comment: I use my phone to test my app, no error, and no crash.

Comment: So you are getting a toast message: _"User data stored"_??? It's really hard to help when it's not clear where the problem is.

Comment: @shinmin did you try the answer?

Comment: i think we cannot write the insert data code inside createuserwithEmailandPassword function right?

Comment: yes you can, you write inside `if(task.isSuccessful(){`

Comment: yaya...I think my project got the problem with the firebase because I use the same code for the new project and new firebase. It works fine. and I try to insert data in a simple way in my old project also failed...Can I ask how can I check the problem because I almost done my work, I don't have time to make a whole new project...

Comment: can I know what is the problem that the project did not execute the code for insert data? because I try to put insert data code in a button.setOnClickListener, and there was no any response after I click the button.

Comment: my code suddenly works, but I still dont know the same code make my app sometimes work and sometimes failed. anyway, thank you all of you  for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the user's email and password after sign up do this:

```
String email=inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
String password=inputconPassword.getText().toString().trim();
FirebaseUser currentUser= task.getResult().getUser();
String userid=currentUser.getUid();
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid);
ref.child("email").setValue(email);
ref.child("password").setValue(password);
```

Then you will have:

```
Users
  userid
    email: email_here
    password: password_here
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: user's data still cannot insert

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32490226/886001) may give you more insight about how firebase handle auth information (email+password)..

Such information is stored in a separate database so if you want to store user data then you have to do it yourself.

You can find [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing) more details on how to store user data.

Comment: This seems to be general advice and not really an answer to this specific question. If you look at the code in the question you can see that OP is actually (trying to) store user data in the database.

Comment: thank you for helping me for my project, my code works!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing plain text password in Firebase? This is a terrible idea. Firebase Auth already hashes and salts your users' passwords. If you ever need to migrate to an external system they provide multiple tools to do so via [CLI SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authimport) and [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).

Comment: Actually I just want to try to insert data according to their UID, I know I dont have to save password.. but now I dont have idea why the code cannot work..

Comment: thank you for helping me for my project, my code works suddenly. maybe my arrangement got problem as I just change my if condition to (task.successfully) and I put the insert code into the if condition.

Comment: You are clearly saving plain text passwords. Please remove that from your snippet.

Comment: May I ask that you guys ever meet the problem that the same code of insert data works previously but after reopening android studio then insert data code not work without changing any code?

Answer (score 0):

here is my code for sign up button. it seems like no changes from the previous, but this one works.

```
        btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!validateForm())
            {
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //create user
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

                                firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                                String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();

                                User my = new User(email,password);

                                ref.child(uid).setValue(my).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                    {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Sign Up successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            finish();
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class));
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            finish();
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main3Activity.class));
                                        }
                                    }
                                });


                            }
                            else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```